# Designing event-based architecture for the customer service

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices, debezium, event-driven, event-driven-design

Being a developer with solid experience, i am only entering the world of microservices and event-driven architecture. Things like loose coupling, independent scalability and proper implementation of asynchronous business processes is something that i feel should get simplified as compared with traditional monolith approach. So giving it a try, making a simple PoC for myself.
I am considering making a simple application where user can register, login and change the customer details. However, i want to react on certain events asynchronously:

1. customer logs in - we send them an email, if the IP address used is new to the system.
2. customer changes their name, we send them an email notifying of the change.

The idea is to make a separate application that reacts on "CustomerLoggedIn", "CustomerChangeName" events.
Here i can think of three approaches, how to implement this simple functionality, with each of them having some drawbacks. So, when a customer submits their name change:

1. Store change name Changed name is stored in the DB + an event is sent to Kafkas when the DB transaction is completed. One of the big problems that arise here is that if a customer had 2 tabs open and almost simultaneously submits a change from initial name "Bob" to "Alice" in one tab and from "Bob" to "Jim" in another one, on a database level one of the updates overwrites the other, which is ok, however we cannot guarantee the order of the events to be the same. We can use some checks to ensure that DB update is only done when "the last version" has been seen, thus preventing the second update at all, so only one event will be emitted. But in general case, this pattern will not allow us to preserve the same order of events in the DB as in Kafka, unless we do DB change + Kafka event sending in one distributed transaction, which is anti-pattern afaik.
2. Change the name in the DB, and use Debezium or similar DB CDC to capture the event and stream it. Here we get a single event source, so ordering problem is solved, however what bothers me is that i lose the ability to enrich the events with business information. Another related drawback is that CDC will stream all the updates in the "customer" table regardless of the business meaning of the event. So, in this case, i will probably need to build a Kafka Streams application to convert the DB CDC events to business events and decouple the DB structure from event structure. The potential benefit of this approach is that i will be able to capture "direct" DB changes in the same manner as those originated in the application.
3. Emit event from the application, without storing it in the DB. One of the subscribers might to the DB persistence, another will do email sending, etc. The biggest problem i see here is - what do i return to the client? I cannot say "Ok, your name is changed", it's more like "Ok, you request has been recorded and will be processed". In case if the customer quickly hits refresh - he expects to see his new name, as we don't want to explain to the customers what's eventual consistency, do we? Also the order of processing the same event by "email sender" and "db updater" is not guaranteed, so i can send an email before the change is persisted.

I am looking for advices regarding any of these three approaches (and maybe some others i am missing), maybe the usecases when one can be preferrable over others?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want event sourcing.  In event sourcing, all you need to store is the event: the current state of a customer is derived from replaying the events (either from the beginning of time, or since a snapshot: the snapshot is just an optional optimization).  Some other process (there are a few ways to go about this) can then project the events to Kafka for consumption by interested parties.  Since every event has a sequence number, you can use the sequence number to prevent concurrent modification (alternatively, the more actor modely event-sourcing implementations can use techniques like cluster sharding in Akka to achieve the same ends).

Doing this, you can have a "write-side" which processes the updates in a strongly consistent manner and can respond to queries which only involve a single customer having seen every update to that point (the consistency boundary basically makes customer in this case an aggregate in domain-driven-design terms).  "Read-sides" consuming events are eventually consistent: the latencies are typically fairly short: in this case your services sending emails are read-sides (as would be a hypothetical panel showing names of all customers), but the customer's view of their own data could be served by the write-side.

(The separation into read-sides and write-side (the pluralization is significant) is Command Query Responsibility Segregation, which sometimes gets interpreted as "reads can only be served by a read-side".  This is not totally accurate: for one thing a write-side's model needs to be read in order for the write-side to perform its task of validating commands and synchronizing updates, so nearly any CQRS-using project violates that interpretation.  CQRS should instead be interpreted as "serve reads from the model that makes the most sense and avoid overcomplicating a model (including that model in the write-side) to support a new read".)

Answer (score 0):

I think I qualify to answer this, having extensively used debezium for simplifying the architecture.

I would prefer Option 2:

- Every transaction always results in an event emitted in correct order
- Option 1/3 has a corner case, what if transaction succeeds, but application fails to emit the event?

To your point:

> Another related drawback is that CDC will stream all the updates in
> the "customer" table regardless of the business meaning of the event.
> So, in this case, i will probably need to build a Kafka Streams
> application to convert the DB CDC events to business events and
> decouple the DB structure from event structure.

I really dont think that is a roadblock. The benefit you get is potentially other usecases may crop up where another consumer to this topic may want to read other columns of the table.

Option 1 and 3 are only going to tie this to your core application logic, and that is not doing any favor from simplifying PoV. With option 2, with zero code changes to core application APIs, a developer can independently work on the events, with no need to understand that core logic.